# Viewing ACLs from S3 console

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, access-control

I’m writing an iOS app where I’m uploading images through S3. I’m currently setting the ACL on image upload using the canned ACLs through the transfer manager as seen in the code below.

```
//do the uploading using the AWS Transfer Manager so we can set the ACL
_uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
_uploadRequest.bucket = @"miltest";
_uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPrivate;
//key = the name of what the image is going to be called
_uploadRequest.key = fileName;
_uploadRequest.contentType = @"image.png";
_uploadRequest.body = url;
```

The image is uploaded fine, however when I view the object’s properties I do not see the set ACL as specified in this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/manage-acls-using-console.html.

I can only see the policy for the bucket owner. Any ideas why the uploadRequest ACL is not being set?

I also noticed that the new transfer utility doesn’t seem to allow the app to set ACLs when uploading objects. Has support for ACLs being removed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is working as expected. The account owner with the full access and no other added grantees is what you should expect from [`AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPrivate`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl).

Also, with Amazon S3 Transfer Utility, you can set ACL using `- setValue:forRequestParameter:` on `AWSS3TransferUtilityExpression`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Didn't realize when it's set as private it wouldn't show anything. 

Thanks for the help on setting the S3 Transfer Utility ACL also.